# How should I create signal for model with placeholder outside in django-cms?

Tags: django-cms

For example, I have model:

```
class Ad(models.Model):

    firm_title = models.CharField(u'Название фирмы', max_length=255)
    placeholder = PlaceholderField('ad_slot')

    changed_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.firm_title
```

And I want to change auto the value of "changed_date" field when I updated placeholder (added or changed plugin). I need it for generate sitemap to use actual changed_date. Now, when I add or update plugin, the "changed_date" field is not updated auto.

As I understand, I should add post_save signal for Placeholder, but I don't know how.

Please, help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a signal for handling that, and the field definition should update the date when you save the object.

I regularly define a created & modified field on tables using these two fields to achieve this same thing;

```
created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunitally, It doesn't work when added or changed plugins in placeholder, because obj of class Ad is not saved. Placeholder is saved...